# Angular6 ngFor directive n-dimentional array

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have an array with objects which can contain childs. And the childs can also contain childs. And so on.

```
[
  {
    name: '1',
    children: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        children: [
          {
            name: '1.2.1'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2'
  }
]
```

I wrote this and it works for 2 levels but I want it to work with n levels:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.name}}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
      {{child.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I could generate it all with typescript, but is there a way to do this with template directives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using templates (`ng-template`/`ngTemplateOutlet`):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bu9poh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<div>Hello world!</div>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemsTemplate;context:{items:items}"></ng-container>


<ng-template #itemsTemplate let-items="items">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    Name: {{item.name}}<br/>
    Children:
    <div style="margin-left:20px">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemsTemplate;context:{items:item.children}"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

You can use ul/li instead of divs.

Comment: For complex components, you should check my answer below with recursive components.

Comment: @Ploppy It depends on how you want the DOM to look like. Having a custom tag, may interfere with layout/styling. Of course you can use component with attribute selector but it gets a bit more messy. You also want to probably comment on the question, not on my answer. I am aware of recursive components.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive html as [this link](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72)

```
<ul>
      <ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">
          {{item.name}}
          <ul *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: list }"></ng-container>
    </ul>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

A really simple way to do it which is also much more suitable for complex components is to use recursive components.

The end result:

```
<app-recursive *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app-recursive>
```

The recursive component:

```
<div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
<app-recursive *ngFor="let child of item.children" [item]="child"></app-recursive>
```

Its typescript:

```
@Input('item') public item: any;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7azst4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html